# Conditional if statement GEKKO

Tags: python, modeling, gekko, ipopt

I am trying to do dynamic modelling of a reactor. To do this, I solved my set of equations first under steady-state conditions (IMODE = 1), and then loaded the steady-state results as initial conditions for my dynamic calculation (IMODE = 7). In my steady-state calculation, I needed to impose that the outlet temperature of my reactor is equal to a certain value. However, I need to remove this condition when proceeding with the dynamic calculation to determine step-response. I have tried the following:

1.) Using conditional if statement

```
if(m.options.IMODE = 1):
  T_outlet == 773
else:
  m.Equation(T_outlet.dt == constants + T_outlet*(long equation with combination of T_outlet and constants)....)
```

2.) fixing and freeing variable

```
m.fix(T_outlet, val = 773)
m.options.IMODE=1
m.solve()

m.free(T_outlet)
m.options.IMODE=7
m.solve()
```

I tried solving the equations using different solvers (IPOPT, APOPT). Unfortunately, none of them work. In my dynamic results, T_outlet = 773 for all time range considered. Is there any proper way of doing this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a new switch parameter `b` that has a value `b.value=1` during initialization and `0` otherwise:

```py
b=m.Param(1)
m.Equation(T_outlet == b*(773) + (1-b)*(...equation...))
m.solve()

b.value=0
m.solve()
```

Comment: Hello sir @John Hedengren, thank you for your suggestion. The concept worked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If it worked, please mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: If I may ask another question sir @John Hedengren, after the implementation of your suggestion, i find that if i perform dynamic mode (IMODE==7) using a pressure value which is constant and equal to the one i used for the steady state simulation, my T_outlet increases with time (this is to determine the pressure step-response of my reactor). Do you perhaps have any idea why this is so? I have validated my steady-state model and it agreed excellently with literature data.

Comment: Could you post another question with the code?